# Avoid Redefinition of require()

Tags: javascript, node.js

Lets consider a case where I would like to override the `require()` function but I want it to avoid further redefinition at some point. Consider the following scenario:

```
// I redefine require here
var _require = require;
require = function(){
   // some code to redefine original require
}
// After this redefinition shouldn't happen
```

I know that it is possible to "freeze" object's function using `Object.freeze(obj)` hence I'm not allowed to modify the object after the statement. But I couldn't find the equivalent of `Object.freeze()` for global/local functions like `require`.

Comment: You in principle can try to freeze global namespace -  `Object.freeze(window)` in browsers. But I am not sure if it will work that way.  window namespace object is kind of special.

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to use

```
Object.defineProperty(window, "require", {
    // current `value` is used
    writable: false,
    configurable: false
});
```

And don't forget to hide `_require` in a closure scope properly.

Comment: Thanks! How to do this in the context of Node.JS (there's no `window` object in Node.JS), can I use something like `Object.defineProperty(GLOBAL,"require")` ?

Comment: Yes, you should be able to use `global`, but I'm not sure whether `require` is actually a global variable in node.js at all.

Comment: @ebudi: see [In what scope are module variables stored in node.js?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/15406062/1048572). So you would only be able to redefine `require` in your own modules anyway, and there you hardly will need to prevent redefinitions.