# can not find required file

Tags: node.js, express

I have a node file used in express which can not see a required file within a function , but when setting breakpoints, I can see it defined right after the declaration. The other variable, `auth` can be seen fine in both places

```
var auth  = require('../utilities/auth'); 
var index  = require('../utilities/index');

// here, i set a break point and index is defined
module.exports = {
    create : function (req, res) {
    // in here, i set a breakpoint, index is not defined
```

And I'm pretty sure I have the paths correct. The snippet above is from user.js 
[image]

a more complete snippet is here . https://gist.github.com/foobar8675/eb5ec78461dff59a80d1

Any suggestions are appreciated!

Comment: Does `utilities/index.js` actually export anything?

Comment: yes, it has this
module.exports = {auth : require('./auth')}

Comment: Do you mind changing the declaration to var utilities=require('../utilities') and use utilities variable instead of index everywhere? By default if you require a folder, index.js is imported

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would be wary of using the name `index.js` in this context as it has special significance when modules are resolved. `index.js` would normally be called when require is passed a folder name, i.e.

```
var utilities = require('../utilities');
```

Can't be sure, but try changing the name of the file to something else like `indexhelper.js` and see what happens.

#### Update

I just ran a test in response to your screencast and I think I can now see your problem. Your invisible `require` vars are not referenced inside the module.exports scope and are thus not being captured. I just ran a test with the following snippet and saw the exact same phenomenon inside the debugger.

```
var mod1 = require("./mod1");
var mod2 = require("./mod2");

//both mod1 and mod2 are visible here
module.exports = {

    init : function() {
        //mod1 not referenced so only mod2
        //is available as a local scope variable in debugger
        mod2.init();
        console.log("module 3 initialised")
    }
};
```

[image: Webstorm debugger snapshot]

So in summary. I don't really think you have a problem here. Just reference  the variable inside module.exports and it will be captured.

See also: [In what scope are module variables stored in node.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15406062/in-what-scope-are-module-variables-stored-in-node-js)

Comment: right now i'm just experimenting and there are some odd things going on. i made a screencast if anyone cares to look and has some can shed some wisdom. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=drk4zxPJnCk&feature=youtu.be