# Mystery of GLOBAL variable in NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js

NOTE : This is just out of curiosity, not a blocker for me as such.

while i was working on my NODE project, i hit something which actually confused me and i could not find why its so.  please find sample code to understand the question

```
function a() {
    console.log(this === GLOBAL);  //true
}    
console.log(this === GLOBAL);      // false
a();
```

Now, [in node documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/globals.html#globals_global)  it clearly says

> The top-level scope is not the global scope

so i understand from above note why `this` is `false`  outside the `function a`(top-level).  but then inside `function a`  `this` is pointing to `GLOABAL`,  why is that ?

i am using `node-5.5.0`,  but i checked the behavior on `node-0.12`, its consistent

may be its some stupid misunderstanding from my side, bear with me.

UPDATE: by the way - `this` in top-level  is `module.exports`, and `this` inside the function is `GLOBAL`

Comment: You are confusing two different concepts. The value of `this` has nothing to do with scope.

Comment: @Quentin : i was trying to find a name for "JS code outside of any function" (like global scope in browser),  in this question i only mean the context in different scope. editing the question

Comment: Have a look at [In what scope are module variables stored in node.js?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/15406062/1048572)

Comment: "*The top-level scope is not the global scope*" makes not much sense, as the global scope is by definition the top-level one. They probably mean "the scope in which module code is executed is not the global one", contrasted to the scope of scripts in a browser.

Comment: @Bergi : Thats from nodejs documentation : https://nodejs.org/api/globals.html#globals_global

Comment: @Bergi : i get it now, http://stackoverflow.com/q/15406062/1048572  was helpful . Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is not related to Node per se but to the ECMAScript spec itself. You might want to read about [Lexical Environments](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-lexical-environments) and [Execution Contexts](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-execution-contexts).

`this` is only `global` in the function call because you’re in non-strict mode; if you were to use the `'use strict';` pragma, `this` would be undefined.

[The MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode#Securing_JavaScript) gives some insight:

> First, the value passed as this to a function in strict mode is not forced into being an object (a.k.a. "boxed"). For a normal function, this is always an object: either the provided object if called with an object-valued this; the value, boxed, if called with a Boolean, string, or number this; or the global object if called with an undefined or null this. (Use call, apply, or bind to specify a particular this.) Not only is automatic boxing a performance cost, but exposing the global object in browsers is a security hazard, because the global object provides access to functionality that "secure" JavaScript environments must restrict. Thus for a strict mode function, the specified this is not boxed into an object, and if unspecified, this will be undefined

So, in non-strict mode, `this` inside a function will default to `global`.

---

Under the hood, Node modules are wrapped in a function call, which will give you access to the `exports`, `require`, `module`, `__filename` and `__dirname` variables:

```
(function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) {
  // your actual code will be injected here
});
```

This function is run using `exports` as the context (i.e. `this`).

Answer (score 0):

In JavaScript, the value of `this` can cause lots of confusion. I'll try to explain just the bits that are relevant here:

- in a 'standalone' function, `this` becomes the global object
- in a method (i.e. a function that is attached to an object) `this` becomes the object whose method is being called

eg.

```
function a() { console.log(this) }
a() //-> logs the global object (window in the browser, global in node)

var obj = { a: function () { console.log(this) } }
obj.a() //-> logs 'obj'
```

Your observations of `this` being set to global are not unique to node and is true in the browser also. There is a thing in JavaScript called "strict mode" which when enabled makes the value of `this=undefined` in the situation we're talking about, which is a much more sensible value.

This article is very informative if you want to understand more about `this`: http://www.2ality.com/2014/05/this.html.

Comment: OP seems to ask about `this` when *not* in a function.

Comment: @Ben : well my question was mostly about `this` being `module.exports` in nodejs(not applicable to browser), in `strict mode` or `non strict mode`.  anyway, the link Berge provided and some other read clears it. Thanks

Comment: @Bergi I figured this was the crux of the question "but then inside function a  this is pointing to GLOABAL, why is that" :)