# Indirect call to eval in strict mode. What happens to x?

Tags: javascript, scope, eval, strict

I've been studying for a job interview, and started digging into JavaScript. Came up with this.

So:

```
"use strict";

var x = 0;
var y = 0;

eval("x=3;y=11;"); //direct call to eval in global scope

console.log("x: " + x); // outputs 3
console.log("y: " + y); // outputs 11
```

But:

```
"use strict";

var x = 0;

(0, eval)("x=3;y=11;"); //indirect call to eval in global scope

console.log("x: " + x); // outputs 0 because the strict mode won't allow the reassignment? 
console.log("y: " + y); // outputs 11
```

I don't know/understand what happens with the x when the eval is executed. I know with strict mode off the assignment goes through no problem. Would anyone be willing to explain this to me? Thanks!

Comment: It prints 3 for me in my console.

Comment: ^ Same. What environment are you running this code in?

Comment: both code sections work the same for me

Comment: I was using node to execute the file.

Comment: @Bargangilo Which version? (`node -v`)

Comment: possible duplicate of [In what scope are module variables stored in node.js?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/15406062/1048572) Try again with global variables.

Comment: If you believe that your job interview is going to be about such arcana, then find another company to interview with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears to be how Node.js handles variables (they do not default to global). The indirect call to eval is assigning to the global object.

```
"use strict";

var x = 0;

(0,eval)("x=3;y=11;");
x++;
console.log("x: " + x); // outputs 1
console.log("global x: " + global.x);  // outputs 3
console.log("y: " + y); // outputs 11
```

Comment: It appears to be how those variables *aren't global* in node :-)