# global scope in chrome and node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-chrome-devtools

When I enter code `console.log(this);` in Chrome dev tools, it displays:

```
Window {stop: function, open: function, alert: function, confirm: function, prompt: function…}
```

but when I execute same code in node.js (v6.11.1) it displays:

```
{}
```

Shouldn't it display information about global object?

(Said code is only thing that is executed, it is not part of a program.)

Comment: Those are all window/browser methods. Why would you expect the global environment for a node module to look like that?

Comment: I was unaware of the fact that this code would be implicitly encapsulated in a 'module'. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the top-level code in a Node module, *this* is equivalent to module.exports. That's the empty object you see. For example:

```
module.exports.a = 'test';
console.log(this); // 'test'
```

In browsers, without using `"use strict"`-directive, *this* refers to global object (Window).

Comment: Thanks, I get it now. Also this questions is spot on: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15406062/in-what-scope-are-module-variables-stored-in-node-js