# What's the argument object within an Arrow function?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

If you access the `arguments` object within an Arrow function, for example:

```
(() => {
    console.dir(arguments);
})();
```

Then you get a large, nested object back:

```
{ '0': {},
  '1':
   { [Function: require]
     resolve: { [Function: resolve] paths: [Function: paths] },
     main:
      Module {
        id: '.',
        exports: {},
        parent: null,
        filename: 
...
```

What is this object? What is its meaning?

Comment: [*"Arrow functions do not have their own arguments object."*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)

Comment: `Uncaught ReferenceError: arguments is not defined`. That's probably the `arguments` of the parent scope.

Comment: @Cerbrus Yep. I think it's the arguments object of the global scope.

Comment: @mizech: The global scope doesn't have an `arguments` object.

Comment: @mizech This looks like the `arguments` object of your node module https://stackoverflow.com/a/15411236/1048572