# How to create a new istance of a global variable in Javascript

Tags: javascript, global-variables, google-cloud-functions

at the beginning of my code, I create a new instance of my global variable DT, but when I try to reassign it a new object in a method my global variable doesn't change.

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const DecisionTree = require("decision-tree")
var firebase = require('firebase-admin');
const cors = require('cors')({origin: true});


......

var boards;
var dt;
var training_dat;

var class_name = "NextMove";
var features = ["C1", "C2", "C3", "C4", "C5", "C6", "C7", "C7", "C9"];

ref.once('value').then(function(snap) {
    boards = snap.val(); // query all data
    training_data = new Array();
    for(var B in boards){
        training_data.push(boards[B]);
    }
    dt = new DecisionTree(training_data, class_name, features);
    // HERE dt is a model with 500 rows.
});



exports.train = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
.....

    dt=new DecisionTree(new_training_data, class_name, features);
//HERE dt is a model with 1000 rows
    response.send({output: "Training"});
});

exports.DOSOMETHING = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
    // if i call dt here it is still a model with 500 rows.
    response.send({output: "Done"});
});
```

So I start my script, I get that dt is 500 rows.
If I call "train" I get that it is 1000 rows.
But when I call "DOSOMETHING" my variable dt has still 500 rows, like the precedent method didn't affect him.

I'm sorry it may sound stupid but I can't figure it out;

Answer (score 1):

Node.js does not put variables declared with *var* into global scope.  ([see related Question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15406062/5217142)).

Whilst you can create a global by assigning a value to `dt` without using the `var` keyword, it errors in strict mode . You could try assigning a value to  `global.dt` instead of `dt`  to create and access a global value without strict mode errors.

Per [Node.js documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_caching) requiring a module multiple times always returns the same cached `module.exports` object that was created when the file was first required. Hence you should also be able to require an empty js file, say `appdata.js`, anywhere you want to access a common name space object within an applicataion.