# How to build TypeScript/JavaScript code by Webpack which will be executed in the Pug pre-processor?

Tags: javascript, typescript, webpack, pug

I want to build some TypeScript code by Webpack and make it available inside [Pug inline code](https://pugjs.org/language/code.html) like:

```
-

  const { formatNumberWith4KetaKanji } = global.__EXPORTS_FROM_LIBRARY__;
 
  const test = 1;
  functionFromTheLibrary(test)
```

Please note that this functinality must be distibuted via Pug files. It means that usage of `locals` of Pug API is not acceptable.

In the question [Which JavaScript runtime the Pug 3.X using?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72723248/4818123) I tried to get the info about JavaScript runtime of Pug, but for this moment, it still unanswered.

We can exclude the Pug from this problem and the question will become to "How to build importable bundle of Webpack from TypeScript which does not using neither `window` nor `module` objects"? I suppose, if I asked such as, I was given the instructions to explaing why I need it.

### Experiments

Try to provide the function [separateEach3DigitsGroupWithComma](https://github.com/TokugawaTakeshi/Yamato-Daiwa-ES-Extensions/blob/master/CoreLibrary/Package/Documentation/Numbers/separateEach3DigitsGroupWithComma/separateEach3DigitsGroupWithComma.md) from the [Yamato Daiwa ES Extensions](https://github.com/TokugawaTakeshi/Yamato-Daiwa-ES-Extensions/blob/master/CoreLibrary/Package/README.md) library.
The source TypeScript file is:

```js
export { separateEach3DigitsGroupWithComma } from "@yamato-daiwa/es-extensions";
```

Once it will be compiled to JavaScript, we can write this code to `.pug` file with leading en dash (I already implemented this automation):

```
-
  // compiled JavaScript code here ...
```

Now, if to setup the Webpack correctly, we can take above function as:

```
include GeneratedExports.pug

-

  const { separateEach3DigitsGroupWithComma } = global.__PUG_EXTENSIONS_EXPORTS__;


.ProductCard
  .ProductCard-Title Lamborghini Urus
  .ProductCard-PriceLabel= separateEach3DigitsGroupWithComma(211321)
```

#### Attempt 1

- **output.target**: web (default)
- **output.library.type**: umd
- **output.library.name**: "**PUG_EXTENSIONS_EXPORTS**"

Generated code:

```js
! function(e, t) {
  "object" == typeof exports && "object" == typeof module ? module.exports = t() : "function" == typeof define && define.amd ? define([], t) : "object" == typeof exports ? exports.__PUG_EXTENSIONS_EXPORTS__ = t() : e.__PUG_EXTENSIONS_EXPORTS__ = t()
}(self, (() => (() => {
  "use strict";
  var e = {
      d: (t, o) => {
        for (var r in o) e.o(o, r) && !e.o(t, r) && Object.defineProperty(t, r, {
          enumerable: !0,
          get: o[r]
        })
      },
      o: (e, t) => Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(e, t),
      r: e => {
        "undefined" != typeof Symbol && Symbol.toStringTag && Object.defineProperty(e, Symbol.toStringTag, {
          value: "Module"
        }), Object.defineProperty(e, "__esModule", {
          value: !0
        })
      }
    },
    t = {};

  function o(e) {
    return String(e).replace(/\B(?=(?:\d{3})+(?!\d))/gu, ",")
  }
  return e.r(t), e.d(t, {
    separateEach3DigitsGroupWithComma: () => o
  }), t
})()));
```

Pug compilation error:

```
Cannot set properties of undefined (setting '__PUG_EXTENSIONS_EXPORTS__')
```

Maybe it refers to `exports.__PUG_EXTENSIONS_EXPORTS__` or to `e.__PUG_EXTENSIONS_EXPORTS__`. Both `exports` and `e` are undefined (in the Pug runtime).

#### Attempt 2

- **output.target**: node16
- **output.library.type**: umd
- **output.library.name**: "**PUG_EXTENSIONS_EXPORTS**"

Generated code:

```js
!function(e, o) {
  "object" == typeof exports && "object" == typeof module ? module.exports = o() : "function" == typeof define && define.amd ? define([], o) : "object" == typeof exports ? exports.__PUG_EXTENSIONS_EXPORTS__ = o() : e.__PUG_EXTENSIONS_EXPORTS__ = o()
}(global, (() => (() => {
  "use strict";
  var e = {
      d: (o, t) => {
        for (var r in t) e.o(t, r) && !e.o(o, r) && Object.defineProperty(o, r, {
          enumerable: !0,
          get: t[r]
        })
      },
      o: (e, o) => Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(e, o),
      r: e => {
        "undefined" != typeof Symbol && Symbol.toStringTag && Object.defineProperty(e, Symbol.toStringTag, {
          value: "Module"
        }), Object.defineProperty(e, "__esModule", {
          value: !0
        })
      }
    },
    o = {};
  e.r(o), e.d(o, {
    separateEach3DigitsGroupWithComma: () => t.separateEach3DigitsGroupWithComma
  });
  const t = require("@yamato-daiwa/es-extensions");
  return o
})()));
```

TypeScript error:

```
require is not a function
```

#### Working code sample

I have working code sample which has been generated a log time ago.
The first lines of the code are pretty similar...

Currently it's unclear which webpack config I have used, but it was actual for the old webpack.

```js
!function(e, t) {
  "object" == typeof exports && "object" == typeof module ? module.exports = t() : "function" == typeof define && define.amd ? define([], t) : "object" == typeof exports ? exports.__PUG_EXTENSIONS_EXPORTS__ = t() : e.__PUG_EXTENSIONS_EXPORTS__ = t()
}(global, (function() {
  return (() => {
    "use strict";
    var e = {
        d: (t, r) => {
          for (var n in r) e.o(r, n) && !e.o(t, n) && Object.defineProperty(t, n, {
            enumerable: !0,
            get: r[n]
          })
        },
        o: (e, t) => Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(e, t),
        r: e => {
          "undefined" != typeof Symbol && Symbol.toStringTag && Object.defineProperty(e, Symbol.toStringTag, {
            value: "Module"
          }), Object.defineProperty(e, "__esModule", {
            value: !0
          })
        }
      },
      t = {};

    function r(e) {
      return function(e, t) {
        return Array.from(e)
      }(e).reverse().join("")
    }

    function n(e) {
      return void 0 === e
    }

    function o(e) {
      let t = e.toString();
      const o = t.startsWith("-"),
        u = t.split(".")[1];
      if (t.length < 5) return t;
      o && (t = t.substring(1)), n(u) || (t = t.replace(`.${u}`, ""));
      const i = r(t),
        a = r(i.substr(0, 4)),
        l = r(i.substr(4, 4)),
        s = r(i.substr(8, 4)),
        c = r(i.substr(12, 4)),
        f = r(i.substr(16, 4)),
        m = r(i.substr(20));
      return (o ? "-" : "") + (m.length > 0 ? `${m}` : "") + (f.length > 0 ? `${f}京` : "") + (c.length > 0 ? `${c}兆` : "") + (s.length > 0 ? `${s}億` : "") + (l.length > 0 ? `${l}万` : "") + `${a}` + (n(u) ? "" : `.${u}`)
    }

    function u(e) {
      return /^[1-9][0-9]*$/u.test(e)
    }

    function i(e) {
      return String(e).replace(/\B(?=(?:\d{3})+(?!\d))/gu, ",")
    }

    function a(e) {
      return String(e).replace(/\B(?=(?:\d{4})+(?!\d))/gu, ",")
    }

    function l(e) {
      return e.replace(/\s{2,}/gmu, " ")
    }

    function s({
      minimalValue: e,
      maximalValue: t
    }) {
      return Math.floor(Math.random() * (t - e + 1) + e)
    }

    function c(e) {
      return e[s({
        minimalValue: 0,
        maximalValue: e.length - 1
      })]
    }

    function f() {
      return Math.random() >= .5
    }

    function m(e) {
      return `mailto:${e}`
    }

    function g(e) {
      return `tel:${e}`
    }
    return e.r(t), e.d(t, {
      buildEmailLinkHREF_ArttributeValue: () => m,
      buildPhoneNumberLinkHREF_ArttributeValue: () => g,
      formatNumberWith4KetaKanji: () => o,
      getRandomArrayElement: () => c,
      getRandomBoolean: () => f,
      getRandomInteger: () => s,
      isStringifiedNonNegativeIntegerOfRegularNotation: () => u,
      replace2OrMoreSpacesTo1: () => l,
      separateEach3DigitsGroupWithComma: () => i,
      separateEach4DigitsGroupWithComma: () => a
    }), t
  })()
}));
```

Comment: Are you passing the compiled javascript file to the pug compiler as a local variable?

Comment: @Sean, consciously - no. Do you mean `output.library.type: "var"`?

Comment: I'm talking about the `locals` object that can be passed to the `pug.compile()` method. How are you compiling Pug—using the package directly or something liek express or gulp?

Comment: @Sean, somewhy most or readers of my questions about above problem are considering the `locals` as solution... Why a can't accept it? Because I want to distiribute my additional Pug functionality via Pug files (in this case, for the user of the lirary, including of this functionality via `include` will be enough). Usage of `locals` means that library user must to change the configuration of his project building system. There are many of theese systems, so I can't documentate the unified solution, herewith the setup of the project building system is not what the begginer engineer can.

Comment: I don't think Pug is engineered to work that way. Have you considered packaging it as a gulp task?

Comment: @Sean, considered - yes, but unfortunately this is the improper solution. Reason 1: user will forced to use Gulp but there are other project building systems. Reason 2: user could have own task which preprocessing the markup. If I'll prepare the Gulp task, it will provide Pug-to-HTML compilation, provide some locals but nothing more. Well, we can exclude the Pug from this problem: how to build the importable TypeScript which does not using neither `window` nor `module` objects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TL;DR**: According to the [doc](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/output/#outputglobalobject), you need to set `output.globalObject`. This config should work:

```
output.target = "web" // default
output.library.type = "umd"
output.library.name = "PUG_EXTENSIONS_EXPORTS"
output.globalObject = "this" // or "globalThis"
```

---

A closer look to your 2 attempts I find them differ in 2 places.

1. For global object, (a) "web" target uses `self`, (b) "node" uses `global`
2. (c) "web" target inlines your package code in the output, while (d) "node" uses `require` to link package.

You want combination of (b) and (c), that's the config I provide above. Problem solved.

Below is me sharing a detour during investigation, which uncovers some technical details in Pug engine, and eventually winds up at a piece of probably lesser known info.

**TL;DR**: `require` is NOT global variable in Node.js (nor are `module, exports, __dirname, __filename`).

---

I know for a fact that Pug is just using Node.js as runtime, that explains 1st error:

```html
Cannot set properties of undefined (setting '__PUG_EXTENSIONS_EXPORTS__')
```

Cus in Node.js `self` does not point to global object. However I don't understand the 2nd error:

```html
require is not a function
```

Why?  I thought `require` is global variable in Node.js.

Out of curiosity I did a bit of code forensics and find out the reason. Check here [link](https://github.com/pugjs/pug/blob/4767cafea0af3d3f935553df0f9a8a6e76d470c2/packages/pug/lib/index.js#L287-L289).

In essence, Pug works like this:

```js
var pugTemplate = fs.readFileSync('./template.pug', 'utf8');
var renderer = pug.compile(pugTemplate, options);
var html = renderer(locals);
```

Tricky thing is how Pug compile. It use [Function constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/Function) to create the `renderer` function.

```
// slightly simplified, not actual implementation
var js = pug.compileBody(pugTemplate, options);
var renderer = new Function('', js);
```

Which, if applied to your code, would look sth like:

```js
var js = `
var pug_html = "";

!function(e, t) {
  e.__PUG_EXTENSIONS_EXPORTS__ = t();
}(global, (() => {
  "use strict";

  var t = require("@yamato-daiwa/es-extensions");
  var _exports = {
    separateEach3DigitsGroupWithComma: t.separateEach3DigitsGroupWithComma;
  };

  return _exports;
}));

return pug_html;
`

var renderer = new Function('', js);

renderer(); //  ReferenceError: require is not defined
```

So I checked [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/Function) and it says:

> Function constructor creates functions which execute in the global scope only.

But it looks fine! Isn't `require` in the global scope? ...unless IT IS NOT! ‍♂️

So I went to check Node.js [doc](https://nodejs.org/api/globals.html#global-objects):

```html
These objects are available in all modules. 
The following variables may appear to be global but are not. 
They exist only in the scope of modules, see the module system documentation:

  * __dirname
  * __filename
  * exports
  * module
  * require()
```

OK, today I learned, `require` is not global variable.

In fact each top level JS file, aka module, before executed in Node.js, is first wrapped in a function like below ([link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15411236/3617380)):

```js
(function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) {
  // module code here
});
```

which means you can even `console.log(arguments)` right at top level. `require` lives in the local scope of this wrapper function, aka module scope, not in global scope.

Comment: I can't thank you enough! Perfect answer: explanations, investigations ... I was need them for both current  and future tasks. By the way your great solution works, of course! I almost has been told that what I want is impossible... With great pleasure, I accept your answer and give the repuration prize!

Comment: My pleasure  BTW if you work with Pug alot, its source code is worth reading. Knowing details that’s not documented empowers you.