# Importing variables from another file on node is confusing

Tags: node.js

I have a node server. This is what my init file looks like:

```
require("variables");
require("constants");
require("index");

app.get('/', function (req, res, next) {
 res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});

httpServer.listen(port, () => {
 console.log(`server running`);
});
```

My variables file looks like this:

```
file = "file.json";
dataopen = "stuff";
userdata = "user";

module.exports={file,dataopen,userdata}
```

whereas my constants file:

```
const button = "<div></div>";
const title = "Page Title";
const input = "submit";

module.exports={button,title,input}
```

The thing here is that if I call for a variable inside index.js it will read it just fine:

```
console.log(dataopen);  //it will output 'stuff'
```

but not so with any constants which will output undefined unless I include this line on top:

```
const { button,title,input } = require("constants");
```

Why is that? Why do I need the extra line for constants but not for variables as well? I also noticed that by removing the prefix `const` before declaring then I won't need the line, but why is that?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [In what scope are module variables stored in node.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15406062/in-what-scope-are-module-variables-stored-in-node-js)

Answer (score 1):

Do a `console.log(global)`. Chance are that you will see your `dataopen` and the other vars.

In a nutshell, by not "declaring" a variable, it will implicitly be global. And when you try to access an undeclared variable, js regards it is a global variable. Something that is not allowed anymore in `strict mode`.

Should not be said, but global vars bad, do not use them.

Comment: Thanks. What about functions?

Comment: Same for functions. If you are coming from php, the `require` aka "let me dump the source code of this file here" works differently from the `require`-commonjs module. It may help if you search for a naive implementation of commonjs's require to get an idea